# How to Set Value of Image from one form to another via VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

When i wanna set value of photo from one form to another form through VBA code using this:

```
Forms![EMP_GRID]![USERPHOTO].Picture = Forms![EMP_PASS_MASTER]![PHOTO].Picture 
or
 Forms![EMP_GRID]![USERPHOTO] = Forms![EMP_PASS_MASTER]![PHOTO] 
or
 Forms![EMP_GRID]![USERPHOTO].PictureData = Forms![EMP_PASS_MASTER]![PHOTO].PictureData
```

It shows an error object does not support this property or method. 
I have used all these but, i don't know how to set value of photo or image. 
Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should have been able to Google pretty easily, I assume that's why you've received downvotes. (You didn't give a lot of information about your question either)

```
Me.ImageControl.Picture = Forms!MyOtherForm.ImageControl.Picture
```

Comment: Did you replace `ImageControl`, `MyOtherForm`, and the second `ImageControl` with the corresponding control names? If you received an error message, what was it? You need to provide information if you want help, we're not mind readers :)

Comment: Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.USERPHOTO.Picture = Forms![EMP_PASS_MASTER]![PHOTO].Picture

end sub

sir i used this but there is no error and also image is not set

Comment: Is your source picture embedded, or linked?

Comment: As long as you are using an Image control, and not some activex or object frame, then it simply works. You must have a different issue that is affecting this. I've tested the following with Access 2013 and it works just fine. `Me.Image0.Picture = Forms("SourceForm").Image0.Picture`

Comment: Edit your question and add the `Form_Load` subroutine. There may be some fault in there that is causing the code we are discussing to not be ran. I hope you're not using `On Error Resume Next`!

Comment: there is a table with has user name, password, user photo.
WHEN i login with user name photo directly comes from table.
i wanna set this(login form) photo to another form(user_entry_form) where user does entry.